# "KeyNotFoundError" in VBA Selenium

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, selenium

I'm learning about how to use Selenium with VBA to automate some Web work. I have a problem with `bot.FindElementById("go").Click`. The problem is that I get this error:

> Runtime error '0':
>
> KeyNotFoundError
>   Dictionary key not found: status

Id of the button really is "go" and this all works on my friend's computer. But on my computer, I get this error message. Does anyone know what might be causing it?

[image: VBA_Selenium_KeyNotFoundError]

Comment: (1) How/why are you sure that the “go”.Click statement is the one triggering the error? (2) Can you identify any relevant differences between the two computers? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Along the line of the suggested by @Scott, add line numbers to your method to confirm that the line reporting the error is the one you think is reporting the error.  You could also place a break (stop) before the line that clicks "go" to confirm that the previous fields are being filled-in.